# Trigger a Jenkins Job when a git commit happens in my repo

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline job. I want my job to be triggered whenever there is a commit in my github repository.

Note: I am able to do this as a freestyle project. Now I want it as a pipeline project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a webhook in a git repository and enable a flag in the job config.

There is a simple [write up with images](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: In the Which events would you like to trigger this webhook? section there is no option for notifying when a commit happens.